# zurb foundation apps notification close button padding

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

The close button on the notification with stock padding is very close to the content. Is there a way to adjust the padding or margin of the close button or does someone have a better recommendation for giving the content of the notification a bit more space from the close button?

Comment: After looking at the element a little more closely (notification), I think what I am looking for is left and right override in sass for the close button. Unfortunately the closebutton sass variable doesn't seem to support left and right.

Comment: So i think the only answer is a mixin of:
.close-button{
top:0.5rem;
right:0.5rem;
}